# Include html pages with Google Closure

Tags: html, google-closure

I'm working with Google Closure. I'm trying to include some html files in another one. Just like A.html import B.html and C.html, but actually, I don't get how to do that.

Can anyone could give some orientation please?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cant "include" html pages like that. The options you got is:

1: use ajax to fetch content

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_net_xhrio.js.html

http://www.googleclosure.com/google-closure-ajax/

2: Google closure templates

https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/?csw=1

3: Use a serverside language like php to include your file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand.

1) Have you HTML in JS and u don't know how to join it?

> - try goog.dom.appendChild(parent, child)

2) You don't know how to get it into JS?

> - You have to send it from server, or If I were in your shoes... use soy templates

Comment: what i mean is that i need to import a html file into another, and i want to know if is there any function in Google Closure to achieve this :)